# Installer not booting on Intel Atom 64bit CPU

Tags: arch-linux, 64bit

I used to have Debian 6, the 64bit version working fine on this system. I'm now trying to install Arch (64bit) and the installer won't boot. Can anybody help me troubleshoot this issue?

EDIT:

My core: http://ark.intel.com/products/43098

Specs: http://pastebin.com/7KVgFch3

Comment: Please describe, what happens if you try to boot. What boot options are used?

Comment: This is rather lacking in description ("the installer won't boot"?), but there's a couple answers that may or may not have fixed the problem, so we might as well leave it open

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail for any help. Just stating that installer wont boot does not help anyone in diagnosing the problem. Please state the error messages that you see.

Comment: I got a `Unknown Paste ID` on that page, was it my connection or ..?

Comment: It's probably because it has expired. This is a very old question that I had asked because my friend was having problems with it, but  I think he'll probably have fixed it by now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it was built for a more typical 64-bit architecture. Atoms are in-order CPUs that lack many features of typical 64-bit processors. Most likely the live system you are trying to boot was built with some gcc optimizations that resulted in instructions not supported by Atom.

You should choose a different live CD/DVD or ask upstream, if one doesn't exist for such CPU.

Comment: This is my core: http://ark.intel.com/products/43098

Comment: Well, the producer is never keen on showing what his product *doesn't* have, right? If you can boot any other livecd, do so and check `/proc/cpuinfo` for a complete set of flags.

Comment: It has the lm flag.
Here's some more info: http://pastebin.com/7KVgFch3

Comment: Yes, I analyzed the cpuinfo already and compared it with CPU flags o my AMD Phenom 2. If that can help, I pasted the flags that are not present in your output here: http://pastebin.com/gSZCjumg

Comment: The said Arch Linux should work out of the box on this processor system. That is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "the installer won't boot"? Do you have a photo/screenshot/log?

I have a Atom 330 and works OK with *BSD and a lot of Linux distros (I haven't tried with Arch).

The best is you open a bug in https://bugs.archlinux.org/ . And try the lastest snapshot of Arch Linux http://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/iso/archboot/latest/ .

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the 32-bit-version. That should work - even with the Atom.

Comment: Instruction Set was 64bit, doesn't that means it support 64bit system?

Comment: @warl0ck The Atom is a strange processor. It is only partly 64-bit - see the accepted answer. I`ve seen other cases with Atoms where 32-bit was working and 64-bit did not.